# Insert a value into range of cell reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to carry over the answer of one formula with another?

This calculates how many cells are populated.

```
=COUNTA('sheet2'!A2:A300)
```

Then, I would like to count how many of the cells in the `column S` are blank dependent on how many cells of column A had data in.

```
=COUNTBLANK('sheet2'!S2:S79)
```

So the `COUNTBLANK` formula will only count up to cell `79`.

Below is the formula I've used for.

```
=COUNTBLANK('sheet2'!S2:S(COUNTA('sheet2'!A2:A300))
```

The reason is, I Paste into `sheet2` the  data dumps that varies from `50 to 290` entries, and I want the formula to detect how many data entries there were and reference all those entries, when looking at column S.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I think you may be using the wrong terminology to describe it.  A count just gives you a number, it doesn't identify qualifying values or ranges.  You can't count how many cells are populated and then use that count in a useful way to qualify things in another column for counting.  The count has already lost all of the detail that defined it.  (cont'd)

Comment: If the goal is to select col S values for counting based on whether the associated col A value is populated, or limit the col S counting range based on how much of col A is populated, or any similar kind of thing, you need to include a condition that actually captures the detail about col A that drives your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last row with data, you want to use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A:$A<>"")*ROW($A:$A)))
```

Inserting in your second formula:

```
=COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("A1:A" & SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($A:$A<>"")*ROW($A:$A)))))
```

(you'll notice the result of the `SUMPRODUCT``is not the same as your first formula, this is normal)